# Is it possible to add a message in the listing of items in Prestashop?

Tags: hook, block, prestashop

I've built my module and made an AdminController that list items from my table, with creation/update/delete/view.

In the listing page, I'd like to add a message after the breadcrumb, but before the table.

I saw there is a hook available : "displayAdminListBefore" and a block to extend "override_header", but I don't know how to make it work!

Can someone could point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add your module to the `displayAdminListBefore` hook.

First hook the module to this hook with the install function:
`public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayAdminListBefore'))
        return false;
    return true;
}`

Then create the hook function like that:
`public function hookDisplayAdminListBefore($params)
{
    return '
    <div class="bootstrap">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            Add your text here
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
}`

Or, you can also use a .tpl:

`public function hookDisplayAdminListBefore($params)
{
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'first_var' => $first_var,
        'second_var' => $second_var',
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/listbefore.tpl');
}`

---

The best way for you will be to override `list_header.tpl` and use the `override_header` hook.

To do so, create a new file `list_header.tpl` in `modules/your_module/views/templates/admin/your_module/helpers/list/list_header.tpl`

In this file copy the following code:
`{extends file="helpers/list/list_header.tpl"}
{block name="override_header"}
    Your text
    {$your_var}
{/block}`

`$your_var` must be defined in your controller in the function `renderList()`:
`$this->context->smarty->assign(
    array(
        'your_var' => 'your_var_value'
    )
);`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. That's what I finally did, but I was wondering: is it possible to make the hook called in my controller, not the module that contains the install method ? My controller that extends AdminController contains informations I'd like to re-use.